# Why we cannot use variables in DataView.ToTable Method() method?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I just need to confirm a few things and would like your suggestion to solve this. Why i can't make `allColumnSelected` as a variable to hold my list of selected column to be shown in datagridview? It just prompt that the columns selected are not belong to the underlying table. When i check the value, it looks like this `"colA","colB","colC"`; which i thought is correct. Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
        string[] allSelectedColumnArr = allSelectedColumn.Split(',');
        foreach(string selectedColumn in allSelectedColumnArr)
        {
            columnSelectedTrim = '"' + selectedColumn + '"' + ",";
            allColumnSelected = allColumnSelected + columnSelectedTrim;
        }    
        DataView view = new DataView(dataTable);
        DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, allColumnSelected);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = distinctValues;
```

Comment: How is `allColumnSelected` declared and populated?

Comment: @Richard Well, i hope that's not the problem. Please check my edited code sir

Comment: Looks like you can remove a lot of cruft and just pass `allSelectedColumnArr` as the second argument - what it wants is a *separate* string for each column - either specified as separate arguments or by passing it as an *array* of strings.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That was simple! Thank you sir!